# How to clear values from Multiple select dropdown?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I am using a amultiple dropdown with check boxes in my web page. For the check box inside the multiselect dropdown  I have used "**multiple-select.js**" plugin from http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/
Whenever after submitting value I try to clear the value from the dropdown , it is not happening i.e. the value is not disappearing. Please suggest if any other ways to do. Here my code snippet below: (If any more information needed please reply)

**CSHTML code**:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                    <div>
                        @Html.Label("Genset")
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Environment, new List<SelectListItem>
                        {                            
                            new SelectListItem() {Text = "ONT", Value = "ONT"},
                            new SelectListItem() {Text = "TST", Value = "TST"},
                            new SelectListItem() {Text = "ACC", Value = "ACC"},
                            new SelectListItem() {Text = "PrePROD", Value = "PrePROD"},
                            new SelectListItem() {Text = "PROD", Value = "PROD"}
                        }, new { @class = "Multiple", multiple = "multiple", style = "width: 126.989px; padding-bottom: 70px;", @id = "ddlEnvironment" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Javascript** :

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){

  var env = $('#ddlEnvironment').val();
  if ( env == null)
        {                                
            //error popup
        }
        else
        {
                    // submit operation using ajax call

                    //I have tried below options, nothing is working 
                     $('#ddlEnvironment').attr('value', null);
                      or
                     $('#ddlEnvironment').val(null);
                      or
                     $('#ddlEnvironment').val('');                    
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the below code you can **uncheck** all the values.

`$('#ddlEnvironment').multipleSelect('uncheckAll');`

Also you can **refresh** the plugin

`$('#ddlEnvironment').multipleSelect('refresh');`

Taken from the **[Plugin Documentation](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#methods)** (navigate to the Methods section)

Comment: No both are not working , just checked ! After refreshing the page only , the value is getting cleared. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: they are using  
$('select').multipleSelect('refresh');
here I have defined "Multiple" as class name and "ddlEnvironment" as ID, what should b there? 
I have checked with
$('.Multiple').multipleSelect('refresh');

Comment: Check with the code I gave... I have used your ID itself.. It must work

Comment: Ok thanks for your help , but not working. Thanks bhai.

Comment: Not working..?? Wait I will add a fiddle and share with you.. In the code I provides I am using the ID as selector.. I don't see a issue for this not to work

Comment: Hey bro its working I just clicked a wrong radio button , logical mistake it was. Its working fine. Thanks a lot bro.